# How to handle DD/MM date time string in Vertica TO_TIMESTAMPTZ?

Tags: date, vertica

I have some date time strings with day first. When I try to convert to TIMESTAMPTZ the month seems to be ignored.
Example

```
TO_TIMESTAMPTZ('01/07/2020 04:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM')
```

Returns

```
2020-01-01T04:00:00.000+00:00
```

I'm looking for 1st July but get 1st January (not even 7th January!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern for minutes is `MI`, not `MM` (see [documentation](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.3.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Formatting/TemplatePatternsForDateTimeFormatting.htm)):

```
dbadmin=> select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('01/07/2020 04:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI');
    TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ
------------------------
 2020-07-01 04:00:00+02
```

Comment: Marco is right. ```MM``` is the path for Months (not minutes).

Comment: Thanks. This outcome is strange though; I would expect trying to put the month in twice as I did would result in an error.